# Emulator cannot enter the showPosition Function - Android PhoneGap

Tags: android, html, cordova

All the functions are working, but it cannot enter the `showPosition` function.

This is the code I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <p id="demo">
        Click the button to get your position:
    </p>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
    <div id="mapholder">
    </div>
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById("demo");

        function getLocation() {
            alert("hellow navigator");
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                alert("inside navigator.loaction");
                //alert(showPosition);
                var tout = 10 * 1000 * 1000;
                options = {
                    enableHighAccuracy: false,
                    timeout: Infinity,
                    maximumAge: 0
                };
                navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition, showError, options);
            } else {
                alert("inside else navigator.location");
                x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
        }

        function showPosition(position) {
            alert("inside Show Position");
            var latlon = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
            var img_url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latlon + "&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
            document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML = "<img src='" + img_url + "'>";
        }

        function showError(error) {
            alert("inside error");
            alert(error.code);
            switch (error.code) {
                case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                    alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.")
                    break;
                case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                    alert("Location information is unavailable.")
                    break;
                case error.TIMEOUT:
                    alert("The request to get user location timed out.")
                    break;
                case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                    alert("An unknown error occurred.")
                    break;
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I allow sharing my location information?  Why do I call the `showPosition` function without parameters, even though it accepts a parameter from me (position)?

Comment: Try using a number for your timeout instead of `Infinity`. And if you don't want a timeout then don't include it in your options, but it's a good idea to have it.

Comment: yes .. i have used limited time like 3 seconds ,, and it always direct me to the showError function taking me to the timeout error !

Comment: Are you using the Geolocation plugin provided by PhoneGap?

Comment: all the required permissions and plugins are done ,,, 
i still can`t get my showPosition function to be invoked :(

Comment: Have you tried removing it? The Geolocation plugin on Android has been known to causes issues and is in the process of being deprecated. If you remove the plugin then it will fallback the the HTML5 Geolocation API, which has the same syntax.

Comment: tried ,, still goes to the time out error ,, still can`t get it to see the success function ,, this code is working very well on wep or any other applications..

Comment: I reformatted your code a little in the way I would've done it. You can view it [here](http://pastebin.com/4bjcz4r2).

Comment: still no progress , it goes to the request timed out error !